# Show that $P_{ij}$ define a probability space on $S \times T$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like to ask for help on how to answer this proving question on infinite probability spaces.

Let $S = { a_1, a_2, ..., a_s }$ and  $T = { b_1, b_2, ..., b_t }$ be finite probability spaces. Let the number $P_{ij} = P(a_i)P(b_j)$ be assigned to the ordered pair $(a_i, b_i)$ in the product set
$S \times T = {(s, t) | s \in S \mbox{ and } t \in T } $

Show that the $P_{ij}$ define a probability space on $S \times T$ i.e. that the $P_{ij}$ are nonnegative and add up to one.

Comment: Why do you speak of "infinite probability spaces" when the ones you discuss are clearly finite?

Comment: To the actual question:  what have you tried?  Can you, say, show that $P_{ij}≥0$?  If you fix, say, $i$, what is $\sum_j P_{ij}$?

Comment: My bad, the question was given under the topic of infinite sample spaces so I thought that it involved it in the solution. I just had a lecture on infinite sample spaces but I have no idea where to start on this question, and there are no references close to this question that I could read up on online.

Comment: I've given you a very strong hint.

Comment: If S and T are probability spaces then they are nonnegative and add up to one. So if i is fixed to 1 in $\sum_{j=1}^t P_{ij}$ then the sum must be nonnegative since $a_1 \epsilon S$ is nonnegative and $b_j \epsilon T$ is nonnegative. Then the same must be true for $a_i$ and $b_j$ so $P_ij$ must be nonnegative. However, I can not figure out how to show that they can add up to one if we multiply the probabilities of $a_i$ and $b_j$

Comment: Just write the sum out explicitly.  Factor out the common term.  What are you left with?

Comment: Note;  you use terms somewhat randomly.  It doesn't make sense to say that a probability space is "nonnegative".  Nor does it make sense to say that  probability spaces "add up to one".  I can guess what you are trying to say but  I think the lack of clarity is getting in your way.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the note... the correct statement is that every element of $P_{ij}$ is nonnegative and their sum add up to one?

Comment: Almost.  "For each $i,j$ we have $P_{ij}≥0$ and the sum $\sum_{i,j}P_{ij}=1$".

Comment: Ok so when I factored out $P(a_1)$ is it correct to just say that the sum of probabilities of $b_j$ is just one, since the probabilities in T add up to one? And if the same can be demonstrated when fixing b, is that enough to state the "For each $i,j$ we have $P_{ij} ≥ 0$ and the sum $\sum_{i,j} P_{ij} = 1$"?

Comment: Again, almost.  You have shown that $\sum_j P_{ij}=P_i$.  But we can write the original sum as $\sum_{i,j}P_{ij}=\sum_i \sum_j P_{ij}=\sum_i P_i= 1$.

Comment: I couldn't figure out for a while how $\sum_i \sum_j P_{ij}$ simplified to $\sum_i P_i$. I just did after 15 mins of thinking and I feel both stupid and mindblown.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck!